# Duplicate a wordpress site on new domain/subdomain

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Usually to duplicate a site on new domain/subdomain

1. I export its content using WordPress export option in dashboard.
2. I install WordPress on new domain/subdomain and connected it to its database as well
3. I use import option in WordPress to import the xml file generated in point #1
4. Then I manually install the plugins required (i.e. installed on live site)
5. Activate the theme, menus and plugins.

---

Is it the right way to do this all or is there any other better way as well to do the same?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general wordpress/server tech support.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a "right way" but it is highly recommended you follow the "Moving Wordpress" guide found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress